# how to sync jplayer playlist jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jplayer

On my music page When I click on music it will open into another window after that jplayer is working fine on that window but I also want to control jplayer from my music page(first page).

```
(document).ready(function(){

  //var getMusic = $.cookie('getCMusic');
  var getMusic = <?php echo $get_music_by_cookie ?>;

  var myPlaylist =  new jPlayerPlaylist({
      jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
      cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
    },getMusic, {
      playlistOptions: {
        enableRemoveControls: true,
        autoPlay: true 
      },
      swfPath: "../../dist/jplayer",
      supplied: "webmv, ogv, m4v, oga, mp3",
      useStateClassSkin: true,
      autoBlur: false,
      smoothPlayBar: true,
      keyEnabled: true,
      audioFullScreen: true,
    });
   });
```

Here is my code ofplay list.
this code is common in both window.

Html code on my music page is :

```
<button class="play">play</button>
 <button class="stop">stop</button>
 <button class="previous">previous</button>
 <button class="next">next</button>
```

Here is my Site: http://www.thathrowdown.com/bespoke/public/#/music

Comment: What do you mean by sync? Do you just want to manipulate this player from another script? If so then declare `myPlaylist` in global scope and then you can call functions on it. Or are you talking about another player manipulating this popup window one?

Comment: I done it by cookie and window.setTimeout function